# How to store data collected from different sources to create dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I am working on creating a dataframe for classification tasks.

Since my data is coming from all kinds of different sources I am wondering what the best way to collect the data step by step would be.

I am starting off with a folder of files, and want to store their path and filename and add new data, such as their label, that I get from a txtfile that is saved somewhere else.

But what is the best way to do that?

I was thinking about a list of dictionary like

```
data = [{"path": path_to_file_1, "filename" : filename_1, "label" : label_1},
    {"path": path_to_file_2, "filename" : filename_2, "label" : label_2}, 
    {"path": path_to_file_3, "filename" : filename_3, "label" : label_3}]
```

and so on .

My idea was to iterate through my folder, collect the information via different functions that I wrote and create a dictionary for each of my files like so:

```
for filename in folder:
   dict_filename={} 
   label=get_label(filename)
   path=get_path(filename)
   dict_filename["label"]=label
   dict_filename["path"]=path
   dict_filename["filename"]=filename
   data.append(dict_filename)
```

with `dict_filename` being a dictionary that only contains the information of the file that I am looking at at the moment.

SO at the end I would get a list containing all the dictionaries that I created for all of my files.

My questions are:

1. Is this a way that makes sense or is there a different way that works better/easier/smoother?
2. If this works, what do I do to create a new dictionary in every loop (I suppose I need a different name for each dictionary so I just don't overwrite my first one with every loop)?

This might be something pretty basic as I am new to Python, but I am grateful for everyone that can help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does the label represent for each file? what is your goal after collecting the data in a dictionary?

Comment: I would like to create a data frame using pandas an thought the list of dictionary would be a good way to do that after doing some research (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) But I am more than open for different solutions if they work better!
The label tells us whats in the file. In the end I want to train an CNN that can tell us whats in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary is the way to go on this one. However, there is a lot of redundancy that could be eliminated depending on the structure of your data.

For example, you can use one dictionary to store all the dataframes in this manner:

```
dfs[filename] = pd.DataFrame(path).rename(label)
```

This basically creates makes accessing the information much easier later on. In addition, you can use:

```
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

To combine all your dataframes in the  end.